# Keyboard shortcut to close attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

You can use a keyboard shortcut in qgis to open the attribute table f6 by default, I believe. However, is there a way to close the attribute table using the keyboard? Could this also be a shortcut?

Answer (score 6):

You can close the attribute table by clicking <kbd>Esc</kbd> while focused on (inside) the attribute table. It doesn't matter if it is floating or docked.

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> just works when it is floating.

Answer (score 4):

Other than pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you could also do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Yes, this works indeed. I always open my attribute table docked, so esc had no effect. By switching to a floating attribute table, no problem.